# Python 3: How to remove matches from 2 lists (full of duplicates) without using set nor collections nor importing anything?

Tags: python-3.x

Please help.

```
>>> a = [7, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2]
>>> b = [2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5]
Expected result:    [2, 7, 3, 5]
```

For a "Pictorial Presentation" , please see
https://www.w3resource.com/python-exercises/python-basic-exercise-32.php

set is not allowed.
collections is not allowed.
Because I am trying to learn loops.

I have tried , without success, doing the opposite of some of the solutions found in
[Intersection of two lists including duplicates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37645053/intersection-of-two-lists-including-duplicates)
Because that thread is trying to do the opposite of what I am trying to achieve.

Please also note this question is not the same question as:
[Python removing items from a list that exist in another list but keeping duplicates that aren't in that intersect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33702549/python-removing-items-from-a-list-that-exist-in-another-list-but-keeping-duplica/33702592)
nor
[Python intersection of two lists keeping duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26663371/python-intersection-of-two-lists-keeping-duplicates)
nor
[Python: intersection of 2 lists keeping duplicates from both lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29830223/python-intersection-of-2-lists-keeping-duplicates-from-both-lists)

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

```
c = list()
for x in a+b:
    if x not in c:
        c.append(x)
```

Comment: Thanks a million for your quick response, mujjiga.

Short and sweet. 

Perhaps you could also simplify some of the solutions found in 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37645053/intersection-of-two-lists-including-duplicates

They are too complicated for me to follow.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: @goughgough np :)  Done added there :)

Comment: Thanks a million. I added a comment to your brilliantly simple to follow solution. This is without doubt the most elegant and easy and simple to follow solution. mujjiga you are a genius. I appreciate your help.